# Why does email sent to my @facebook.com address always end up in Facebook messages spam?

Tags: facebook, email

I'm trying to figure out how my `<myusername>@facebook.com` address works with regard to sending messages back and forth to non-Facebook email addresses (in the messages area). The ultimate goal is to be able to send users of my Facebook page-tab private messages (something that Facebook has apparently purposefully made difficult).

I don't want to resort to sending them a non-Facebook account email.

I can successfully send a message *out* to an email address from `<myusername>@facebook.com`, but any replies or direct messages from an outside email address end up in spam.

The only info I can find on Facebook about the `@facebook.com` email addresses:

- [How do I use my @facebook.com email address?](https://www.facebook.com/help/224049364288051)
- [What is my Facebook email address? Where does this address appear?](https://www.facebook.com/help/202977306410418/)

Nowhere can I find any info about how their spam filter works. I do, however, see lots of people referring to the "other" tab as the spam. In fact, it’s my impression that almost no one has any idea that the spam folder exists (it’s hidden under "more").

Is there a way to send messages to my users `@facebook.com` address and have it NOT show up in spam (which, as far as I can tell, all but guarantees they will never see it)?

Comment: Hi, any luck with that? I facing the same problem.

Comment: @Asaf unfortunately no. As far as I can tell, its not possible to prevent these messages from going into spam - which apparently is how Facebook intends it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You will only get messages if they are sent by people in your friends list. Messages sent by others will go to your spam box. Otherwise, you would be getting thousands of spammy messages by people who could get your username easily.